# Nativescript Issue with Image URLs

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-angular

[Playground Test Link](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=GYAGpS&v=379)

When I use the local Images with (~), it is working. But when I change the relative path to URL(https://via.placeholder.com/150.jpg), it throws an error.

It is working for https://nativescript.org/assets/ns-logo_share_600x315.png but not for https://via.placeholder.com/150.jpg or https://via.placeholder.com/150.png or any else. How can I set it so that it can accept images from any server? Is it supposed to be a server related issue as I checked the headers and mostly all are the same.

As per the [docs](https://docs.nativescript.org/ui/components/image), we can dd URLs to Image tag but it is still not working. Please help me rectify this issue.

**Error**

> [Galaxy Note8]: Error in downloadBitmap -
> java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://via.placeholder.com/150.png

Tried all file types: jpg, png, jpeg, gif